# Azure active directory integration with azure app services.

Tags: active-directory, azure, domain-controller, entra-id, azure-web-apps

I am not a Azure and Microsoft guy but there is a friend of mine who is stuck in a situation where he need user attributes like, phone, email, address, etc from Azure active directory for his application hosted on Azure app service. they have developed the website on PHP/Wordpress and also able to authenticate their wp-admin users from Azure Active directory however what is left they need other attributes to store in sql database. so any suggestion which one is the best practice to achieve this?

Thanks,
Yousuf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have your users in an Azure AD Tenant, then you already completed step one. Step two is to use Graph API to get this kind of information.

**Quickstart for the Azure AD Graph API**

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api-quickstart

**Sample: Calling the Azure AD Graph API from a PHP web app**

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-php-graphapi-web/

Make sure to read about permissions as well. This is important if you need to get complete user and group profiles in your application.

**Permission scopes | Graph API concepts**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-permission-scopes?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396